# Comments conrtoller test ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

When run `rake test`, I get this error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError`

my routes.rb

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [ :create,:destroy ]
  end
```

comments.yml

```
one:
  body: "comment one"
  user: users(:paul)
  post: posts(:one)
```

comments_controller_test.rb

```
  def setup
    @comment = comments(:one)
  end

  test "should redierct create when not signed in" do 
    assert_no_difference "Comment.count" do
      post :create, comment: @comment.attributes
    end
    assert_redirected_to signin_url
  end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
    @comment.save
    @comments = @post.comments.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

Complete error message

> ERROR["test_should_redierct_create_when_not_signed_in",
>   CommentsControllerTest, 0.444971] 
>   test_should_redierct_create_when_not_signed_in#CommentsControllerTest
>   (0.44s) ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches
>   {:action=>"create", :comment=>{"id"=>"980190962", "body"=>"comment
>   one", "post_id"=>"849819558", "user_id"=>"293831562",
>   "created_at"=>"2014-11-16 10:45:03 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-11-16
>   10:45:03 UTC"}, :controller=>"comments"}

How should I modify my test code?

Comment: not sure but try replacing `redirect_to @post` in comments_controller with `redirect_to [@post,@comments]` !

Comment: It's not working, I think `post :create, comment: @comment.attributes` maybe is the main reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly tell about the parent record id (post_id) so rails can form the correct post path, try something like:

```
post :create, comment: @comment.attributes, post_id: @comment.post_id
```

Comment: Thank you, It works! But I still have doubts, Why `@comment.attributes` not contain `post_id`?

Comment: it does contain it (as in error message hash output) but when asking to form a post request Rails can't figure the correct path >> post_comments_url  without passing post_id as a parameter. Try to read more about nested resources routing .. hope this helps!